# select from that doesn't contain info

Tags: mysql, psql

Let me try and re-explain what I'm trying to do. First off I have a database or items that is huge, 50k and more, growing daily. I need to pull information from this database based on what it does not have. (I'm using SQL; pSQL or MySql doesn't matter.)

So the database looks like this (roughly)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

```
+---------+--------+
| ITEM    | TYPE   | 
+---------+--------+
|    12EU | P      |
|    12EU | R      | 
|    12EU | T      |
|    34RE | P      |
|    34RE | R      |
|    34RE | T      |
|    54TR | R      |
|    54TR | T      |
+---------+--------+
```

Not all items have "P" but they all have "T" and "R." I need to pull the ITEM that do not have a TYPE "P," the ITEM's with other letters do not matter to me.

In this example I would want ITEM "54TR" because it does not have a TYPE "P."

I hope this helps better explain what I am trying to do.

EXAMPLE of what I have done:

```
SELECT distinct ITEM 
FROM (SELECT distinct ITEM FROM my_table WHERE TYPE='P') q 
WHERE TYPE!='P'
AND ITEM != q.ITEM
ORDER BY ITEM
```

This does not work, it still returns other types, not the right track...

Comment: It's always a good idea to really post the desired result set in addition to the source data. And it's often helpful to name the DBMS, too.

Comment: 54TR has a P,34RU and 34RE do not have a P , is that right ?

Comment: No 54TR does not have P the others do. Using !='P' in the where clause returns all items that don't have P but that's to much info. I need the items that don't have P at all.

Comment: the last line of your table is : 54TR P, please clarify.

Comment: Updated post to makeep it clear.

Comment: yes, that's what i thought, try the "minus" solution below, POC done by @danielhilgarth on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct item from yourtablename where type!='P'
minus
select distinct item from yourtablename where type='P'
```

example :

```
create table myt (item varchar2(10),atype varchar2(10),piece varchar2(10));
insert into myt values ('12EU','P','ext');
insert into myt values ('12EU','R','ext');
insert into myt values ('34RE','T','ext');
insert into myt values ('54RT','P','ext');
insert into myt values ('34EU','R','ext');
insert into myt values ('54TR','P','ext');
commit;
```

SQL> select * from myt;

```
ITEM       ATYPE      PIECE
---------- ---------- ----------
12EU       P          ext
12EU       R          ext
34RE       T          ext
54RT       P          ext
34EU       R          ext
54TR       P          ext

6 rows selected.
```

SQL> select distinct item from myt where atype!='P'
  2  minus
  3  select distinct item from myt where atype='P';

```
ITEM
----------
34EU
34RE
```

Comment: This looks redundant.

Comment: Why exactly do you need a "MINUS SELECT..."? The first SELECT row already does the job.

Comment: indeed, using redundancy to try optimizing a bit the request avoiding explicit joins, the table size is 50K.

Comment: the first select gives the items that have other types than P(ie normal items) , the second those that contains P (confirmed P items), the minus will give the normal items that are not P-items.

Comment: @Gar: No, that makes no sense. The result set of the first query never can contain items that would be returned by the second query. The two result sets are [disjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets). In other words: The result of the first query and the result of the combined query is always the same.

Comment: @Daniel, actually it does, look at the sample table, "item" is not a key, item/type is a key, well unless i didn't unserstand the question, running this minus query returns the two elements 34EU and 34RE (i'll update the answer with the DDL)

Comment: @Gar: Sorry. Yes, you are completely correct. Thanks for your patience... Here is a fiddle demonstrating it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e6de/1  +1

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it is all good, thank you for the fiddle (didn't even know it existed :) ), hope this solves the problem for the op.

Comment: This works great can'to believe I didn't think of minus, great work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from my_table t
where type != 'P'
AND not exists 
        (select 1 from my_table t2 where t2.item = t.item and t2.type = 'P')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wih following SQL query

```
select * from yourtablename where Type  not like '%P%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tablename where type != 'p'
```